# Cannot connect to mongolab using createConnection()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I cannot connect to mongolab using the following code :

```
// DATABASE CONNECTION
var db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:11168/db1');
var db2 = db1.useDb('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:12341/db2');
```

Im trying to create a multiple connection across 2 databases so I used `.createConnection()` for the first db and then `db1.useDb()` for the second db. This works perfectly fine for `localhost` but when I switch to mongolab everything crumbled down.

There's nothing wrong with my mongolab setup and all because when I use just the `connect()` function : `var db1 = mongoose.connect('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:11168/db1');` It connects without a problem. However when I used the given codes above (the first block of codes) it results to this error : `MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '.'`

My goal is to be able to connect to multiple database on mongolab.

Am using the latest mongoose npm.

Comment: Considering the error given it's not likely that either of your examples are your actual connection string ( and please don't post that ), but the error would of course point to the exact problem in your actual connection string.

Comment: Yes of course their not the actual connection uri. But as I said it worked perfectly when I used `.connect()` using the very-exact-same mongolab uri.

Comment: @BlakesSeven anyways it's fine I figured out a solution to this problem.

Comment: Well it had to be a "typo" which is why I immediately voted to close as such. But you should close yourself really since there would be nothing here of benefit to others by such a mistake.

Comment: @BlakesSeven It had to be, but there is none. if you copy and paste a string will the system accidentally create a type on the fly? I think not. Don't get me wrong but I know how to see a "typo"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. I will post this answer for future reference in case someone might cross the same problem.

Note the following code :

```
var db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:11168/db1');
var db2 = db1.useDb('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:12341/db2');
```

Instead of using `db1`'s connection, I instead use this :

```
var db1 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:11168/db1');
var db2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://foo:bar@ds011168.mlab.com:12341/db2');
```

Let `db2` have have it's own connection.

**Disclaimer**, I don't know yet if this is the proper way to do this but for the mean time it solves the problem. Maybe by doing this you can just create 2 connection event checking for both `db1` and `db2`

Comment: How is this an answer to `MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '.'`?

Comment: Well it solve the problem. Im trying to solve the problem which resulted to `MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '.'` not the problem per se. And please read  the disclaimer before down voting a working solution. I clearly said that "That might not be the proper solution" and I only posted that as a reference in case someone might cross the same problem.

Comment: Okay fair enough, as there is a difference between "swicthing databases" and a completely new collection. But it still is a very basic mistake that you should have realized.